# Angularjs : How to use <md-radio-button> inside <table> with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying data as a table. The user has to select a row from the table. So I tried using `<md-radio-button>`, But it is throwing an error saying `<md-radio-group>` directive is missing. Could anyone tell me how to use `<md-radio-button>` inside  with ng-repeat?

```
 <table md-table>
        <thead md-head>
          <tr>
            <td md-cell></td>
            <td md-cell>ID</td>
            <td md-cell>Demand</td>
            <td md-cell>Code</td>
          </tr>
        </thead md-head>
        <tbody md-body>
        <md-radio-group ng-model="test" class="md-primary">
          <tr md-row ng-repeat="cluster in clusters">
            <td md-cell>       
             <md-radio-button ng-value="cluster.checked"/>
            </td>
            <td md-cell>{{cluster.id}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{cluster.demand}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{cluster.code}}</td>
          </tr>
          </md-radio-group>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is the code,

```
 <md-divider></md-divider>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="cc.selectedIndex">
    <div ng-repeat='person in cc.contacts' class="row">
      <div flex layout='row' layout-padding layout-align="start center">
        <div flex style="max-width:200px;">
          {{person.Demand}}
        </div>
        <md-radio-button ng-value="person.ID" class="md-primary">
          {{person.Code}}
        </md-radio-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </md-radio-group>
  <md-divider></md-divider>
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/18DT6TtiuNhmyAfZAgPb?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `md-radio-group` and `md-radio-button` inside table exactly the way you did. The reason your code doesn't work is not obeying the ["always use a dot rule"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=31m8s).

[this is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/M4sTaL?p=preview)

Comment: The working example posted has the `md-radio-group` within the `td`. As opposed to the OP which has it wrapping the `<tr ng-repeat="...">`. This fixed my issue